# jquery Triggering click event dependent on url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that clicks a tab if the hash is equal to a certain value. I can get it to alert from a hash but every time that I attempt to have the hash result in a click I get no response. I'm newer to this so I'm sure it's something simple.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$("#nav-page_requests-tab").click(function() {
            window.location.hash = '2';
        });

var currentValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(currentValue == '2'){
                $("#nav-page_requests-tab").click();
            }
        });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-page_requests-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-page_requests" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-page_requests" aria-selected="false">Page Requests</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your click event binding inside ready function like:

```
var currentValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#nav-page_requests-tab").click(function() {
             window.location.hash = '2';
           });

           if(currentValue == '2'){
              $("#nav-page_requests-tab").click();
           }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. There's still no click on the element that I want it to.